# Getting the co-ordinates of a component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

How to get the co-ordinates of a JSF component after onclick event ? I need to place an overlay just below an icon that was clicked.

Is there any such in-built facility provided by JSF rather than manually writing a javascript function for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to BalusC's answer, here is an example, where a click on a component with `id=placeholder` (maybe a link or button) will open another component (`id=menu`) directly below the triggering component. If the mouse is moved away from the triggering component, the menu will disappear:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#placeholder").click(function(event) {
    //get the position of the placeholder element
    var pos = jQuery(this).offset();
    var height = jQuery(this).height();
    //show the menu directly below the placeholder
    jQuery("#menu").css( { "left": pos.left + "px", "top": (pos.top + height) + "px" } );
    jQuery("#menu").show();
  });
  // hide the menu on mouseout
  jQuery("#placeholder").mouseout(function(event) {
    jQuery("#menu").hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

The component with `id=menu` can be a `div` or a jsf `h:panelGroup` or any other component. The `style` attribute with `display: none` will initially hide the component:

```
<h:panelGroup style="position: absolute; display: none;" id="menu">
  <!-- content here -->                
</h:panelGroup>
```

Make sure that the jQuery id selector gets the correct id of the component. E.g. if your elements are inside a form with `id=form1`, the jQuery call has to look something like this:

```
  jQuery("#form1\\:placeholder").click(function(event)
```

Notice the double backslash.

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't. The position is browser (client) dependent. In the client side there is also totally no means of JSF, it's all just plain HTML/CSS/JS. The location can only be extracted from the HTML DOM element. You'd have to pass it from JS to JSF or do the business job fully in JS instead of JSF.

As PrimeFaces ships with jQuery, your best way to retrieve the element position relative to the document is using [`jQuery.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

```
var $element = jQuery('#someid');
var offset = $element.offset();
var x = offset.left;
var y = offset.top;
// ...
```

Answer (score -3):

I'd recommend using a JSF component library like RichFaces or IceFaces. Many of them have AJAX capabilities and JavaScript library integration, and therefore have components for doing that kind of thing.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that one either. However, nothing technical prevents you from adding more libraries if you find one that does what you're looking for out of the box. They (should) all play together nicely.

Comment: You should review the differences of server side (JSF) and client side  technologies (javascript).